# Jquery create selector from button ids

Tags: jquery

There are 4 types Manual Automatic Disel and Benzin.

```
<button id="all">All</button>
<button id="Manual">Manual</button>
<button id="Automatic">Automatic</button>
<button id="Benzin">Benzin</button>
<button id="Diesel">Diesel</button>
```

If a Manual or Automatic selected selector would be its name. But Automatic and Manual can't select together. So if one is active other must be not. Same thing for Benzin and Diesel too.

But if Automatic or Manual  And Benzin or Diesel Selected, selector will be $('.Automatic.Benzin') or etc...

How can i do it with jquery? I tried something but did not have success.

Here is my try.

```
var selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function () {
if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
    selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
    $(".btn").removeClass("active");
    $(".btn").first().addClass("active");
}
else {
    var allIndex = $.inArray("all", selectedVehicleTypes);
    if (allIndex > -1) {
        selectedVehicleTypes.shift();
        console.log(selectedVehicleTypes);
    }

    var catIndex = $.inArray(this.id, selectedVehicleTypes);
    if (catIndex > -1) {
        selectedVehicleTypes.splice(catIndex, 1);
    }
    else {
        selectedVehicleTypes.push(this.id);
    }

    if (selectedVehicleTypes.length == 0) {
        $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
        selectedVehicleTypes = ["all"];
        $(".btn").removeClass("active");
        $(".btn").first().addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(".btn").each(function (index, el) {
            if (this.id.length > 0) {
                var selector = "." + this.id;
                console.log(selector)
                var btnIndex = $.inArray(this.id, selectedVehicleTypes);
                if (btnIndex > -1) {
                    $(selector).fadeIn(450);
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
                else {
                    $(selector).hide();
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry i am very newbie for jquery and javascript.

Comment: If you have mutually-exclusive buttons, why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: because they want

Comment: You can use CSS to make the radio buttons look like ordinary buttons.

Comment: Hmm i'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really confusing, looks like you are doing a lot of things for not really much... Do you know your selector can use variables, right? like

```
<button id="all">All</button>
<button id="Manual">Manual</button>
<button id="Automatic">Automatic</button>
<button id="Benzin">Benzin</button>
<button id="Diesel">Diesel</button>

<div class="vehicle all Automatic">car 1 automatic</div>
<div class="vehicle all Automatic">car 2 automatic</div>
<div class="vehicle all Benzin">car 1 benzin</div>

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.vehicle.all').hide(); // hides all vehicles
    $('.vehicles .'+$(this).attr('id')).show(); // show just vehicles with the id
});
```

assuming you have .vehicles and .all (for the all type) as a class for the vehicles and each vehicle type as the same class as the button id so: .Automatic, .Manual, etc..

Don't forget to set some of then as display:block; at first run using css

---

EDIT:

Based on your comment, it should be something like this: (https://jsfiddle.net/tfLf8Lgr/1/)

```
<button id="all">All</button>
<button id="Manual">Manual</button>
<button id="Automatic">Automatic</button>
<button id="Benzin">Benzin</button>
<button id="Diesel">Diesel</button>

<div class="Automatic Benzin">Automatic Benzin</div>
<div class="Automatic Diesel">Automatic Diesel</div>
<div class="Manual Diesel">Manual Diesel</div>
<div class="Manual Benzin">Manual Benzin</div>

var current_engine = '';
var current_cartype = '';
var engines = ['Automatic', 'Manual'];
var cartypes = ['Benzin', 'Diesel'];

$('button').click(function() {
  var selected = $(this).attr('id');

  if ($.inArray(selected, engines) !== -1 || selected == 'all')
    current_engine = selected;

  if ($.inArray(selected, cartypes) !== -1)
    current_cartype = selected;

  // hide based on engines, hide all then
  $.each(engines, function(k, v) {
    $('.' + v).hide();
  });

  // show everything based on engines, all then
  if (current_engine == 'all') {
    $.each(engines, function(k, v) {
      $('.' + v).show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.' + current_engine + '.' + current_cartype).show();
  }
});
```

At current state you need to change BOTH types (engine and cartype) to work

Comment: thanks for answer. But my car class must be like this <div class="Automatic Benzin"> or <div class="Automatic Diesel"> or <div class="Manual Benzin"> or <div class="Manual Diesel"> so i can hide all then show according to created selector $('.Automatic.Diesel').show()

Comment: Edited it, not perfect as you wanted but you can figure something out from it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying on my local but if you clicked manual  all manual must be show ( diesel or benzin ) or similar